# problems installing libdc1394v2

Tags: ros, stereo, bumblebee

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone. I am new to ROS and am currently working on getting the Bumblebee2 node (By Soonhac Hong, source: http://cu-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/bumblebee2) to work properly in Ubuntu 10.10 for my Pt grey Bumblebee2 stereo camera . When I use rosmake to build the bumblebee2 package I am consistently getting an error:

"
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/cturtle/ros/bin/rospack deps-manifests bumblebee2

[rospack] couldn't find dependency [libdc1394v2] of [bumblebee2]

[rospack] missing dependency
"

This results in a successful build of 5 packages with one failure...

So I I tried installing libdc1394v2 as per instructions on the distributor's website... I am still having the same problem.

If it isn't already obvious, I am also quite new to Ubuntu and I'm not even certain if I am installing this package properly. I followed the instructions, any idea why I am still having problems launching this node? I apologize if I sound like a complete idiot here, I am very eager to learn more but I am at a loss as to what I need to do to educate myself. I feel like it may be my lack of Ubuntu knowledge and not a lack of ROS knowledge that is holding me back.

I have attempted to run the camera using coriander... I receive an error that states that it does not detect any camera connected to the bus. The camera works properly in a Windows environment.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

UPDATE:

Following the instructions of user joq, I edited the manifest.xml file in the bumblebee2 package and created a rosdep.yaml files with gedit. I am now getting a new error:

"
ros@ros-SG45:~$ rosdep install bumblebee2

Failed to find stack for package [libdc1394-dev]

Failed to load rosdep.yaml for package [libdc1394-dev]:Cannot locate installation of package libdc1394-dev: [rospack] couldn't find package [libdc1394-dev]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/cturtle/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/ros/bumblebee2:/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks]

executing this script:

set -o errexit

No Packages to install
"

I was under the impression that the ros-cturtle-camera-drivers were installed when I installed the ROS + base version in the first place. If this is incorrect, then how do I determine if these drivers are already installed / how do I install them? If ros-cturtle-camera-drivers were the name of a package I would know what to do, but it isn't (as far as my search has told me) so I'm not sure what software you are referring to specifically.

I have gone through all of the bus permission troubleshooting per joq's advice as well, to no avail. The camera still is not working with coriander, and I also tried it using Kino. No luck. However, I was presented with another issue when attempting to add a raw1394 specific udev rule, as described at (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Firewire#Method%203.%20%27udev%20rule%27):

"
ros@ros-SG45:~$ modprobe -r raw1394 && modprobe raw1394

FATAL: Error removing raw1394 (/lib/modules/2.6.35-25-generic-pae/kernel/drivers/ieee1394/raw1394.ko): Operation not permitted
"

I'm just running into problem after problem here!

Thanks again!

Rob

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9198/problems-installing-libdc1394v2/) by [rob-bot](https://answers.ros.org/users/185/rob-bot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2011-02-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe there is a newer version of the `bumblebee2` package, I don't know.

That dependency is now out of date. There does still exist a [libdc1394v2](http://www.ros.org/wiki/libdc1394v2) package in `camera_drivers_experimental`, but it is no longer maintained. You may be able to download and compile that package from SVN, but I do not recommend it.

The simplest solution is probably to replace the `<depend package="libdc1394v2"/>` in the package manifest with a `<rosdep name="libdc1394-dev"/>`. To resolve that dependency either install `ros-cturtle-camera-drivers` or else create a `rosdep.yaml` in that package with these stanzas:

```
libraw1394-dev:
  ubuntu: libraw1394-dev
  fedora: libraw1394-devel

libdc1394-dev:
  ubuntu: libdc1394-22-dev
  arch: libdc1394
  fedora: libdc1394-devel
  macports: libdc1394
```

Your problem with `coriander` is most likely a common Ubuntu device permissions problem. See: [bus permissions troubleshooting](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera1394/Troubleshooting#No_Bus_Access_Permissions).

If you need more details, post a follow-on comment.

[Edit: responses to follow-on questions posted as an "answer"]

If you updated the `rosdep.yaml`, you should no longer need the `libdc1394v2` package.

The reference to `<camera_info_manager/camera_info.h>` is out of date (predating cturtle). The released version should include `<camera_info_manager/camera_info_manager.h>`, which is part of the `camera_drivers` stack in cturtle (moved to `image_common` in diamondback). I think you have that already.

The dependencies on `camera_info_manager` are *package* dependencies, they use the `<depends>` tag in the `manifest.xml`, not `<rosdep>`. The (obsolete) `camera_info.h` does *not* belong in the include file of the `bumblebee2` package.

You are correct that the inability of Ubuntu to find your camera is a separate problem.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rob-bot](https://answers.ros.org/users/185/rob-bot/) on 2011-02-27**:
Thank you so much for the help! Following your instruction, I edited the manifest and created the rosdep.yaml files in a text editor with your code. I am now getting a new error which I have described in an update to my original questions.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I also face this problem which take me a long time. and I find a solution which can solve it. Just like joq, while I give the details about it. and I reference to [Soonhac Hong](http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/Does-cturtle-not-have-everything-boxturtle-does-td1030354.html)

and I paste his below for more people:

Quick set of simple patches to make your code compile against C-turtle:

```
Index: manifest.xml 
=================================================================== 
--- manifest.xml    (revision 17)
+++ manifest.xml    (working copy)
@@ -11,7 +11,7 @@ 
<depend package="tf"/> 
<depend package="camera_info_manager"/> 
<depend package="dynamic_reconfigure"/> 
- <depend package="libdc1394v2"/> 
+ <rosdep name="libdc1394-dev"/> 
</package>

Index: src/bumblebee2.cpp 
=================================================================== 
--- src/bumblebee2.cpp    (revision 17) 
+++ src/bumblebee2.cpp    (working copy) 
@@ -52,7 +52,7 @@ 
#include <sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h> 
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h> 
#include <tf/transform_listener.h> 
-#include <camera_info_manager/camera_info.h> 
+#include <camera_info_manager/camera_info_manager.h> 
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h> 
#include <dynamic_reconfigure/server.h> 
#include <dynamic_reconfigure/SensorLevels.h> 
Index: src/dev_camera1394.cpp 
=================================================================== 
--- src/dev_camera1394.cpp    (revision 17) 
+++ src/dev_camera1394.cpp    (working copy) 
@@ -34,6 +34,7 @@ 
#include <stdint.h> 
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h> 
+#include <dc1394/dc1394.h> 
#include "bumblebee2.h" 
Index: CMakeLists.txt 
=================================================================== 
--- CMakeLists.txt    (revision 17) 
+++ CMakeLists.txt    (working copy) 
@@ -33,6 +33,6 @@ 
#rosbuild_add_boost_directories() 
#rosbuild_link_boost(${PROJECT_NAME} thread) 
#rosbuild_add_executable(example examples/example.cpp) 
-#target_link_libraries(example ${PROJECT_NAME}) 
+rosbuild_add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/bumblebee2.cpp 
src/dev_camera1394.cpp) 
-rosbuild_add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/bumblebee2.cpp 
src/dev_camera1394.cpp) 
+target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} dc1394)
```

---

Originally posted by [Yongqiang Gao](https://answers.ros.org/users/162/yongqiang-gao/) with karma: 133 on 2011-03-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yongqiang Gao](https://answers.ros.org/users/162/yongqiang-gao/) on 2011-03-03**:
Yeah, and thanks a lot to u.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-03-03**:
This answer was accidentally flagged as "offensive". It is not. We are still trying to figure out how to remove that marker. Sorry for the confusion.